# Python 3.7: Applying the proxy to all parts of pip installation, failing to maintain the proxy variable

Tags: python, pip

I have the below problem, I am using command

```
pip install pyinstaller --proxy=http://webdefence.global.blackspider.com:80 --trusted-host=pypi.python.org
```

The problem I have is the proxy variable is not maintained through the installation process. It no longers has the proxy address when trying to install setuptools. I have tried using `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in my environment variables with no luck. Are there any other ways to set a proxy which will maintain through the pip install?

I have used -vvv to produce more error detail - pasted in at  `gist.github.com/blaggrob/19e7afcae2b4f1d36139fbf0a88a6651`

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\blaggr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\blaggr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vd3w15r1 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org -- setuptools wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
    Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/setuptools/
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

Comment: You can also set the proxy information in a configuration file, see the [*using a proxy server* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server). However, I find it surprising that the options are not carried across properly. I haven't confirmed this, but perhaps you should put the options *before* the packages? `pip install --proxy ... PyInstaller`.

Comment: Is there a way to know if it's reading from the ini file? I'm using the PIP_CONFIG_FILE environment variable but doesn't look like my ini file is being read.

Comment: Have you tried creating a file in `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini.` then? That would be `c:\users/blaggr\appdata\pip\pip.ini` on your system.

Comment: Hi Martijn, I tried that and put the below into my ini file but it still didn't work. I'm not sure if it's even reading it. [global] proxy=http://webdefence.global.blackspider.com:80 [install] ignore-installed = true

Comment: That's... surprising. Together with other issues, I'm beginning to think you have a very old or broken pip installation, or something else that wraps the real pip. Can you add `-vvv` to the command line (very, very verbose) to get a detailed log of what pip thinks is going on?

Comment: Hi Martijn,
I just ran it using -vvv, anything in particular I should be looking out for. The only things I really noticed were.
`Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect` Looking around, it looks like these are just warnings.

Comment: I would have to see the output, your setup appears to be having issues with reading configuration (command-line switches, the config file), so it may even be the *absence* of certain outputs that would be interesting, when compared with a working system running the same command.

Comment: Hi Martijn,the output is too big to paste here, can I send it to you?

Comment: This is the last line `pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "c:\users\blaggr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\blaggr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2dnv8whp --no-warn-script-location -v --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org -- setuptools wheel" failed with error code 1 in None`

Comment: You can use an online pastebin service, e.g. https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Hi Martijn, here is my gist. https://gist.github.com/blaggrob/19e7afcae2b4f1d36139fbf0a88a6651

Comment: I suspect this could be a bug in the new PEP 517 / 518 support. Can you try adding `--no-build-isolation` to the command line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may have run into a bug with the new [PEP 518 support implementation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4144), where the isolated build environment created to install build-time dependencies is lacking the necessary proxy configuration.

You can bypass the new feature by using `--no-build-isolation` on the command line, by setting `no-build-isolation=no` in your configuration file or by setting the `PIP_NO_BUILD_ISOLATION=no` environment variable (yes, these last two options are [counter-intuitive](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2897)).

This does require that `setuptools` and `wheels` then are already installed before you can install `pyinstaller`.

I've [filed a new issue with the `pip` project](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6018) to track this, I don't believe it has been reported before.

Comment: We seem to have this same issue but `--no-build-isolation` seems to have no effect, the subprocess pip install still does not get the internal mirror repo details and fails with the same error. In my case the issue is with `weasyprint==52.5` which specifies `cffi>=1.1.0` in requires.txt. Any ideas what else could be the issue in my case?

Answer (score 5):

The bug is still present 4 years later but there's a reasonable workaround! Credit and thanks to q0w from the Pypa project who posted to the issue that @MartijnPieters linked in his answer.

Set the environment variable `PIP_PROXY` instead of using the `--proxy` command-line argument. The pip subprocess finds and uses the env var just fine.  Here's an example of pip 22.3.1 installing a source tarball with a `pyproject.toml` file and its dependencies via a corporate proxy server:

```
% export PIP_PROXY=http://the.proxy.mybigcompany.com:8080
% pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/50/c4d2727b99052780aad92c7297465af5fe6eec2dbae490aa9763273ffdc1/pip-22.3.1.tar.gz 
Collecting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/50/c4d2727b99052780aad92c7297465af5fe6eec2dbae490aa9763273ffdc1/pip-22.3.1.tar.gz
  Downloading pip-22.3.1.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 851.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
```

Comment: no idea this was a thing but it 100% fixed my issue with pip subprocess failing to install (connection timeout). Thank you!

Comment: How do other projects online get around this, as I can install them using the `--proxy` just fine? I am trying to write a library to share online and am wondering if this is something I need to account for.