# pip install pyinstaller fails with unable to connect to proxy where I don't have any proxy settings

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to install pyinstaller using --proxy="" to avoid any proxy conlflicts but still it failing while Installing build dependencies and trying connect proxy which I had not mentioned anywhere.

```
    Processing c:\users\downloads\pyinstaller-pyinstaller-v4.0-86-gad39eb8.zip
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\mahesh.beeravelli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q0ktyno1\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
    cwd: None
Complete output (7 lines):
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002CF7FEB3610>, 'Connection to orrproxy.mphasis.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002CF7FEB3DC0>, 'Connection to orrproxy.mphasis.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002CF7FEB3F70>, 'Connection to orrproxy.mphasis.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002CF7FEB3E80>, 'Connection to orrproxy.mphasis.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002CF7FEB3F10>, 'Connection to orrproxy.mphasis.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Solved this issue after removing proxy settings from %userprofile%/pip/pip.ini even though I am using --proxy="" dependent packages are taking the proxy config looks bit weired

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
--no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517 -vv
```

to your command line.  It worked for me.

See

[Python 3.7: Applying the proxy to all parts of pip installation, failing to maintain the proxy variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280131/python-3-7-applying-the-proxy-to-all-parts-of-pip-installation-failing-to-main)

[Build Error, pip is trying to build a wheel using "pep517" #28633](http://%20https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28633)