# why does xlwings not install?

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I uninstalled xlwings and then tried to install it again but now I get this error all the time:

[image]

I have no issues with other pip installs.

Any clues?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875) Could you copy-paste the actual text into your question?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a fix.

I added `--no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517` to pip.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970507/pip-install-pyinstaller-fails-with-unable-to-connect-to-proxy-where-i-dont-have)

[See also](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1853)